UI does not update after inserts into SQLite DB on iOS SwiftUI
Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I can not get the JobsView to update the UI in real time when I insert jobs into the table. Please see some of my code below, let me know if any other further info is needed:
JobsView.swift:
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct JobsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    
    @StateObject private var webSocketManager = WebSocketManager.shared
    @EnvironmentObject private var databaseManager: DatabaseManager
    
    @State private var selectedJobs: Set<Job> = [] //Tracks selected Jobs
    @State private var navigateToPODView: Bool = false //Controls navigation to POD view
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                // List with selection from local db
                List(databaseManager.jobs, id: \.id, selection: $selectedJobs) { job in
                    HStack {
                        if selectedJobs.contains(job) {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.green) //Shows a checkmark for selected jobs
                        }
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("\(job.CustomerName)")
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("\(job.Address1), \(job.Suburb), \(job.State)")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Text("Invoice: \(job.InvoiceNo)")
                                .font(.footnote)
                        }
                        .contentShape(Rectangle()) //Makes the entire row tappable
                        .onTapGesture {
                            toggleSelection(for: job)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.inset)
                    .navigationTitle("Jobs")
                
                
                // Action button to proceed to POD view
                Button(action: {
                    navigateToPODView = true
                }) {
                    Text("Sign POD (\(selectedJobs.count) selected)")
                        .bold()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
                        .background(selectedJobs.isEmpty ? Color.gray : Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding()
                }
                .disabled(selectedJobs.isEmpty) // Disable button if no jobs are selected
            }
            //.onAppear {
            //    databaseManager.fetchJobs()
            //}
            
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigateToPODView) {
                PODView(selectedJobs: Array(selectedJobs))
            }
        
        }
    }
    
    private func toggleSelection(for job: Job) {
        if selectedJobs.contains(job) {
            selectedJobs.remove(job)
        } else {
            selectedJobs.insert(job)
        }
    }
}

DatabaseManager.swift:
import GRDB
import Foundation
import Combine

class DatabaseManager : ObservableObject {
    
    // The database file URL
    private var dbQueue: DatabaseQueue!
    
    //Publisher for jobs updates
    @Published var jobs: [Job] = []
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        do {
            // Specify the SQLite database file location (it will create the file if it does not exist)
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let dbPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("job.sqlite")
            
            dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: dbPath.path)
            
            // Create the jobs table if it doesn't already exist
            try createJobsTable()
            
            //Observe database changes
            observeJobs()
            
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing database: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    // Create jobs table
    private func createJobsTable() throws {
        try dbQueue.write { db in
            try db.create(table: "job", ifNotExists: true) { t in
                t.autoIncrementedPrimaryKey("id")
                t.column("JobId", .integer)
                t.column("PickTicketId", .integer)
                t.column("DriverId", .integer)
                t.column("InvoiceNo", .text)
                t.column("CustomerName", .text)
                t.column("Address1", .text)
                t.column("Address2", .text)
                t.column("Address3", .text)
                t.column("Suburb", .text)
                t.column("State", .text)
                t.column("Pcode", .text)
                t.column("Cartons", .integer)
                t.column("Created", .text)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Observe jobs table for changes and update the @Published property
    private func observeJobs() {
        let observation = ValueObservation.tracking() { db in
            try Job.fetchAll(db) //Fetch all jobs whenever there is a change
        }
        
        observation
            .publisher(in: dbQueue)
            .catch { error -> Just<[Job]> in
                print("Database observation error: \(error)")
                return Just([]) // Return an empty array if there's an error
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] jobs in
                self?.jobs = jobs
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    
    func insertJob(job: Job) {
        do {
            try dbQueue.write { db in
                try job.insert(db) // Use GRDB's insert method
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error inserting job: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

At the moment the Jobs view is empty, only when i restart the app the jobs populate.

Can you show the code where/how you declare your ...databaseManager = DatabaseManager()
and how you pass it to your JobsView from the parent view.

Below is the entry point to the app:
struct WadsTrackerNewApp: App {
StateObject private var appState = AppState()
StateObject private var databaseManager = DatabaseManager()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(appState)
            .environmentObject(databaseManager)
    }
}

}
